# Compile cgo lib on Cygwin64: "ld: cannot find -lmingw32"

Tags: gcc, go, sqlite, cygwin, cgo

I'm trying to use a cgo library on Windows, namely `github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3`

I use Cygwin64 and installed with all "Development" packages, so gcc is availabe.

But running `go get github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3` results in:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lmingwex
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lmingw32
```

If I search for "mingwex" and "mingw32" in the Cygwin installer, I get no results. Am I looking for the wrong names or are they not available on 64 bit systems?

Or is there a better way to use the library on Windows?

---

Note that the README states that

> However, if you install go-sqlite3 with go install
>   github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3, you don't need gcc to build your app
>   anymore

but I get the same error message if I use `go install`.

```
$ go version
go version go1.6.2 windows/amd64
```

Comment: gcc is for building on Cygwin for Cygwin. mingw32 is for building for Windows. May be you want to use the cross compiler `/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe` from Cygwin to Windows ?

Comment: @matzeri thanks for the suggestion, but I can't figure out how to tell go, which `gcc` binary to use. Actually, building for cygwin would be fine for me too, if I can get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: I do not see go as cygwin package, so building for cygwin seems complicated. Look if setting CC or GCC variable is effective

Comment: On mingw64 I needed to install `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What finally worked for me (instead of Cygwin) is to download TDM MinGW-w64 from http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download and set the PATH such that gcc from `C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin` is used.

Comment: For reference, the issue is clarified [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/cherry/+/master/README) `- MinGW: http://www.mingw.org/
  * add "c:\MinGW\bin" to PATH
  * run "mingw-get install gcc"
  * required for building sqlite Go package
  * note: using Cygwin GCC doesn't work`

Answer (score 4):

You can also install package `mingw64-i686-gcc-core` from Cygwin.

The binary will be `/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe` so you probably need to copy it as `/usr/bin/gcc.exe`.

Comment: ```/usr/bin/gcc.exe``` file is already present. Should I replace it with the existing ```gcc.exe``` file?

Comment: This works for me, too. I installed mingw64-x86_64-gcc-core (not i686) via cygwin setup and then:
`export CC='D:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe'`

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same issue as well. It seems to me that cygwin is not fully compatible with cgo. Instead, I have used https://mingw-w64.org.

From the cgo documentation https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo:

> In order to use cgo on Windows, you'll also need to first install a gcc compiler (for instance, mingw-w64) and have gcc.exe (etc.) in your PATH environment variable before compiling with cgo will work.