# Any Ideas how to solve this cygwin Go build error

Tags: go, cygwin, build-error

I am building a go program for windows with cygwin. I cannot find a solution to this problem any where. any help would be useful.

```
C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/usr/lib/w32api/libntdll.a(dmsqs01966.o):(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `pow'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/libm.a(t-d000990.o):fake:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/w32api/libntdll.a(dmsqs01956.o):(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `log'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/libm.a(t-d000824.o):fake:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/w32api/libntdll.a(dmsqs01934.o):(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `ceil'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/libm.a(t-d000253.o):fake:(.text+0x0): first defined here
C:\cygwin64\tmp\go-link-845985599/000001.o: In function `x_cgo_sys_thread_create':
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_libinit_windows.c:12: undefined reference to `__imp___iob_func'
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_libinit_windows.c:12:(.text+0x6): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp___iob_func'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\go-link-845985599/000001.o: In function `x_cgo_thread_start':
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_util.c:43: undefined reference to `__imp___iob_func'
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_util.c:43:(.text+0xdc): relocation truncated
```

EDIT 1:
Someone sugested using 1.8 but another error msg

```
C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: running gcc failed: exit status 1
C:\cygwin64\tmp\go-link-485496143\000001.o: In function `_cgo_preinit_init':
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_libinit_windows.c:28: undefined reference to `__imp___iob_func'
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_libinit_windows.c:28:(.text+0x6a): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp___iob_func'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\go-link-485496143\000001.o: In function `x_cgo_sys_thread_create':
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_libinit_windows.c:56: undefined reference to `__imp__beginthread'
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_libinit_windows.c:56:(.text+0x10c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp__beginthread'
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_libinit_windows.c:58: undefined reference to `__imp__errno'
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_libinit_windows.c:58:(.text+0x11e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp__errno'
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_libinit_windows.c:58: undefined reference to `__imp___iob_func'
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_libinit_windows.c:58:(.text+0x126): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp___iob_func'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\go-link-485496143\000001.o: In function `x_cgo_notify_runtime_init_done':
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_libinit_windows.c:99: undefined reference to `__imp___iob_func'
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_libinit_windows.c:99:(.text+0x255): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp___iob_func'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\go-link-485496143\000001.o: In function `x_cgo_thread_start':
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_util.c:18: undefined reference to `__imp___iob_func'
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_util.c:18:(.text+0x32c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp___iob_func'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\go-link-485496143\000001.o: In function `_cgo_sys_thread_start':
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_windows_amd64.c:32: undefined reference to `__imp__beginthread'
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_windows_amd64.c:32:(.text+0x403): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp__beginthread'
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_windows_amd64.c:34: undefined reference to `__imp__errno'
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_windows_amd64.c:34:(.text+0x415): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp__errno'
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_windows_amd64.c:34: undefined reference to `__imp___iob_func'
C:/workdir/go/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_windows_amd64.c:34:(.text+0x41d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp___iob_func'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/libmingwex.a(lib64_libmingwex_a-ftruncate.o):ftruncate.c:(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `_chsize'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/libmingwex.a(lib64_libmingwex_a-ftruncate.o):ftruncate.c:(.text+0x1): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_chsize'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/libmingwex.a(lib64_libmingwex_a-_fstat.o):_fstat.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `_fstat64'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/libmingwex.a(lib64_libmingwex_a-_fstat.o):_fstat.c:(.text+0xf): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/libmingwex.a(lib64_libmingwex_a-log.o):log.c:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `_errno'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-
```

Comment: Why are you trying to build a go program from cygwin? While there might be a way to make it work, its not a supported use-case, and Go is natively supported on windows.

Comment: i need to use `make` and cygwin is my compiler of choice

Comment: I'm fairly certain that for cgo especially, you're going to need to use mingw.

Comment: What is your `golang` version? According to [https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8756](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8756), the issue should be fixed in `go1.8`. I'm agree with JimB. Personally, I'm using [http://www.msys2.org](http://www.msys2.org). `Go` package and `MinGW` compiler are provided in the repository, and is uptodate.

Comment: Use MinGW. See: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497354/compile-cgo-lib-on-cygwin64-ld-cannot-find-lmingw32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497354/compile-cgo-lib-on-cygwin64-ld-cannot-find-lmingw32)

Answer (score 7):

We had to remove cygwin and install this compiler http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download , and we had no problems.

Remember to remove the cygwin gcc compiler from your PATH

I hope it'll help you.

Comment: This solved it for me! I tried a ton of different compiler installs and this one just worked. One note for future readers - I did have to delete and re `go get` the package I wanted to use so that it compiled with the new GCC install and worked with the resulting `go build`. Until I did this I still got errors. Thanks so much!

Comment: `go run -a` did the work for me. -a is forcing rebuild