# Can't compile Go application using cgo through TDM-GCC on Windows

Tags: sqlite, go

I've got the TDM-GCC-64 distribution installed, and set to the PATH variable. I still can't install the cgo distribution [github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3](http://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3). I had CygWin installed before I read the most relevant answer to the question ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497354/compile-cgo-lib-on-cygwin64-ld-cannot-find-lmingw32)). However, installing the tdm distrubution has made no difference.

I get the following error on trying to run the application:

```
c:\go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lmingwex
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lmingw32
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your Go installation is still using Cygwin distribution to invoke `gcc` very likely because of `PATH` environment variable setting. Try prepending your `PATH` environment variable with path to Mingw64 distribution `bin\` directory (this will not persist so you need to try `go run` in same Command Line window):

```
set PATH=C:\Path\To\Mingw64\Installation\bin;%PATH%
go run whatever.go
```

(NOTE: make sure you have `\bin` there. If your Mingw64 distro is installed in `C:\Mingw64` it will be `C:\Mingw64\bin`)

If above helped and you want to fix this permanently (and you don't depend on Cygwin tools in Command Line as doing below will replace some commands with Mingw64 ones) make sure that in your `PATH` environment variable path to Mingw64 is before the Cygwin path. You can do this by doing following:

1. Press *Windows Key + R* to bring up *Run dialog*
2. Type `rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables` and press Enter to bring System variables dialog
3. In the top section called *User variables for USERNAME* double-click the row where Variable column is `Path` to bring up *Edit Environment Variable* dialog
4. Now check if row where is path to your Mingw64 installation /bin directory is **above** the row where path to your Cygwin installation /bin directory is. **If it is below click on it to select it and click *Move Up* button as many times as needed to bring it above Cygwin path**.
5. Once done close both dialogs with *OK* button

While you can install mingw64 packages in Cygwin it is very likely not compatible with Go tooling and [official documentation](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsBuild#install-mingwmsys) recommends Mingw64/MSYS as a compiler suite to get `gcc` - I strongly recommend using latest distribution linked in documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I removed Cygwin from my system entirely, since I'd installed it solely for this purpose. Moving the Path to Mingw64 to near the top of the environment variables, and then restarting the console and VSCode (which had its own consoles open)  did the trick for me.