# cgo seems broken on stock go on stock cygwin - is it supported?

Tags: go, cygwin, cgo

Running any simple "Hello, world!" that uses cgo on a (current as of today) stock cygwin generates an error:

> ```
> $ go version
> go version go1.16.5 windows/amd64
>
> $ go test -run TestCamera
> # runtime/cgo
> gcc_libinit_windows.c: In function ‘x_cgo_sys_thread_create’:
> gcc_libinit_windows.c:58:12: error: implicit declaration of function ‘_beginthre
> ad’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
>    58 |  thandle = _beginthread(func, 0, arg);
>       |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
> cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
> ```

Is go not supported on cygwin for some reason?  Or, how can I fix this?

example code:  literally any cgo, for example https://github.com/kyleconroy/hello-cgo/blob/master/hello.go

Comment: Literally any cgo.  I added a link to an example "Hello World!" using cgo, but just writing it (it's obvious/trivial as any Hello World) should be faster than downloading that.   If not, I don't see how it's even possible to answer this...   (and, it's a question "does <x> support <y>", not at all about a particular piece  of code)

Comment: No, Cygwin is not supported.

Comment: JimB - Can you point to some official document which describes which environments are supported under windows (or in general), and which are not?  I could not find such a thing in the docs.

Comment: Go supports both windows and Linux natively. Cygwin is not officially supported by the fact that there no declaration of support. It is a platform with a lot of quirks, and the go team has no interest or time  to try and work around its bugs when native support is available.

Comment: But cgo depends on a C compiler, so it must have a C compiler.   So some set of C compilers must be supported.  It therefore depends on a C library, so some subset of C libraries must be supported.  There's no such thing as "native" C compilation!

I am asking which compilers/C libraries are supported. I can't imagine that no one has ever thought about that / written it down / told users...

Comment: The error looks like the main problem is that go detects it's running under `windows/amd64` while you want it to use this fake gnu-linux environment, so it still may be the fact that Cygwin is not supported. You may be able to override things with `GOOS`, `CC`, or `CC_FOR_TARGET`, but you're just fighting the tooling. As for which c compiler is supported, `cgo` generally targets `gcc`, and `mingw-w64` is recommended here: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo#windows.

Comment: "(for instance, mingw-w64)" is not really sufficient.  That describes a /family/ of toolchains, I want to know exactly which are supported.   If you're not familiar with cygwin, it's two things: 1) a set of binaries / distribution of GNU software, and 2) a compatibility library which you can link against. The tools use (2), and one of the several toolchains that ship with Cygwin use (2) by default.   mingw-w64 compilers are in Cygwin, don't do (2), and Go shouldn't care what runs the compilers.  I still need a support matrix.  Seperate question / not for comments,  tho.

Answer (score 2):

If I download these files [1], I can run these commands as expected:

```
PS C:\hello-cgo> go mod init hello
PS C:\hello-cgo> go build
PS C:\hello-cgo> .\hello.exe
Hello CGO!
```

However I should say that I am not using Cygwin, but MSYS2 [2]. Specifically, these
packages:

```
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
mingw-w64-x86_64-binutils
mingw-w64-x86_64-crt-git
mingw-w64-x86_64-gmp
mingw-w64-x86_64-headers-git
mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthread-git
mingw-w64-x86_64-windows-default-manifest
mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads-git
mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib
mingw-w64-x86_64-zstd
```

I think if you use Pacman, you can just install the first one, and it will pull
in the rest (I use my own MSYS2 package manager). I know this is not quite what
you asked for, but maybe it will help you.

1. https://github.com/kyleconroy/hello-cgo
2. https://repo.msys2.org/distrib

Comment: This isn't really an answer (because I'm asking about Cygwin), but was the hint I needed to at least find a workaround, because this target toolchain exists in cygwin as well.   Things /seem/ to work if I set the CC environment variable to the compiler mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc.exe in the Cygwin shell.   But it would be nice to know what Go's actual requirements and support matrix is!   Perhaps this is another question...

Comment: @BadZen as someone with extensive Cygwin experience (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1002260+[cygwin]) - I will say that Cygwin is an awful platform for programming. I would strongly suggest dumping it for MSYS2 or even https://github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw - do yourself a favor

Comment: Not an option, sadly :/

Answer (score 0):

I have no problems running go on cygwin after installing `mingw64-x86_64-gcc-core` and
`export CC='D:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe'` as described on https://stackoverflow.com/a/43615612/2935741.